# Checking if array contains a number (Issue with 0)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of numbers. The array may contain a zero.

How can I check if the array contains a number or not? I am currently doing that:

`if (Number(arr. value(pos)) != false)`

This however, considers `0` as false too. So if a 0 is in the array, it will consider it as if the array was empty.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

`if (Number(arr. value(pos)) !== false)`

`!=` does a "falsy" check. `0, undefined, false, null, '',` and `NaN` are all falsy. Everything else is "truthy". If you want to test for false only (and not all other falsy statements) you have to use `===` or `!==`. Try to avoid `!=` and `==`, because most if the time you actually mean `!==` and `===`

Comment: I guess he can just do `if (Number(arr. value(pos))` which will evaluate to true

Comment: He can't do that because `Number(arr. value(0))` evaluates to false

Answer (score 1):

koenp's answer is perfectly correct, but 
`if (!isNaN(arr. value(pos)))` might be preferable in this case.  Also, it may be a notch faster.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp

Answer (score 0):

> might be a solution. It checks whether the Number is bigger than Zero.